# How to represent nested one to many relationship in android room?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Here are **sample POJO**:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @PrimaryKey
  public String id;
}

@Entity
public class Pet {
  @PrimaryKey
  public String id;
  public String userId;
  public String petName;
}

@Entity
public class Category {
  @PrimaryKey
  public String id;
  public String petId;
  public String categoryName;
}
```

Here is my **UsersWithPets** class to fetch all the users along with pets.

```
public class UserWithPets {
  @Embedded
  public User user;
  @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "userId", entity =   Pet.class)
  public List<Pet> pets;
}
```

**My user Dao**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
  List<UserWithPets> loadUsersWithPets();
}
```

**and userdb**

```
@Database(entities = {User.class, Pet.class, Category.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
public abstract class UsersDb extends RoomDatabase {

  private static UsersDb INSTANCE;

  public abstract UserDao userDao();

  public static UsersDb getInstance(Context context) {
      if (INSTANCE == null) {
          synchronized (UsersDb.class) {
              if (INSTANCE == null) {
                  INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), UsersDb.class,
                          "User.db")
                          .build();
              }
          }
      }
      return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

The "**UserWithPets**" embeds user object and relates with its associated list of "**Pet**", but how do I fetch list of "**Category**" if my "**Pet**" POJO can have 1-many relationship with "**Category**".

Also the user DAO only returns all the "**User**" along with its "List<**Pet**>" by mapping the id between `user.id` and `pet.userId`, if my "**Pet**" POJO can have many "**Category**"(List of Category), how do I create my DAO and abstract database class such that querying for a particular "**User**" id will return me the "**User**" object along with its "**List of Pets**" and individual "**Pet**" containing a "List of **Category"** and querying for all will return all the "**List of Users**" wherein each User contains a "**List of Pet**" and each **Pet** contains a "**List of Category**"

Comment: check [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a)

Answer (score 19):

You need to map your query to a POJO/Java Bean class like PetWithCategories:

```
public class UserWithPets {
  @Embedded
  public User user;
  @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "userId", entity = Pet.class)
  public List<PetWithCategories> pets;
}

public class PetWithCategories {
  @Embedded
  public Pet pet;
  @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "petId")
  public List<Category> categories;
}
```

Comment: seems to work, when i want to query user with  pets i get "an enclosing instance that contains UserWithPets.PetWithCategories is required" . That error is in my UserDao_impl Class .......... fixed it was because PetWithCategories Class was inside UserWithPets

Comment: This saved me hours of work just only putting entity on the first relation. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably it would be easier to start additional database requests after you finished the first one. I don't see any way to realize that via @Relation or with inner joins as this is not a single value you want to return. You could use left join, but that would give you multiple pets, only with different category objects.

```
List<UserWithPets> list = userDao.loadUsersWithPets();
for(UserWithPets user : list) {
   for(Pet pet : user.pets) {
      pet.categories = categorieDao.getCategoriesByPetId(pet.id); 
      //pet.categories should have the @Ignore annotation
   }
}

...

@Dao
public interface CategoryDao {

   @Query("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE petId = :petId")
   List<Categories> getCategoriesByPetId(int petId);
}
```

Comment: So if I have 4 - 5 nested one to many relations that just means that I have to request for each one and query them to get the results back individually? How does that make building database any easier with Room?

Comment: Yeah it seems. Well, Room is not build to focus on nested relations between objects but to make programming with databases much easier for devs. Google tried to make that clear here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#no-object-references. You could take a look at this url https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#entities-nested-objects if you really want to use the nested objects as Embedded objects (but it is not the same as you originally wanted).

Comment: @Mordag where does it mention that room is not designed for nested relations 
 between objects?